# Is it possible to populate a variable in a literal string using bash

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am currently getting a value from dynamodb and storing it as an env var which is the s3 bucket name of where i store my terraform state which is tf-state-$ENV.

I am wanting to substitute $ENV in the string with another environment variable i have set inside of jenkins for the relevant environment e.g. dev, test etc as this is the only difference between the environments.

```
export tf_bucket=$(aws dynamodb --region eu-west-1 get-item --table-name terraform-jenkins-params --key '{"module": {"S": "compute"}}'| jq '.Item.tf_s3_bucket[]')

echo $tf_bucket 
tf-state-$ENV

echo $ENV
dev

Wanted output
echo $tf_bucket
tf-state-dev
```

This can be done either using bash or in jenkins, I was trying to avoid using sed etc if possible.

Comment: Your code cannot produce the output you get from `echo $tf_bucket`

Answer (score 2):

Use bash pattern substitution:

```
tf_bucket=${tf_bucket//"\$ENV"/$ENV}
```

This replaces all occurences of `$ENV`.

A single slash replaces only the first occurence:

```
tf_bucket=${tf_bucket/"\$ENV"/$ENV}
```

edit:

This could introduce a code injection vulnerability, but it's possible to use `eval` to actually expand any variables in the string:

```
eval "tf_bucket=$tf_bucket"
echo "$tf_bucket"
# gives
tf-state-dev
```

Or similarly, use `$tf_bucket` with `bash -c`:

```
export ENV
bash -c "echo $tf_bucket"
# gives
tf-state-dev
```

Comment: jq can access environment variables directly

Comment: Piping it through `envsubst` would be safer than using `eval`, but would replace all environment variable references, not just `$ENV`.

Answer (score 1):

Piping through envsubst as suggested by @gordon-davisson worked a treat, thanks for all of your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` directly for this, like in this example:

*test.json*

```
{
  "Item": {
    "tf_s3_bucket": [
        "tf-state-$ENV"
    ]
  }
}
```

in bash:

```
export ENV=foo
jq '.Item.tf_s3_bucket[]|sub("\\$ENV";$ENV["ENV"])' test.json
```

**Note:** Don't get confused by the doubly use of `ENV` in the above example. That's because `$ENV` is a reserved variable in jq, containing an array with all environment variables. Because you named your variable also ENV, it's `$ENV['ENV']`